# Set password for VM users when OS Login is enabled: Authentication token manipulation error

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I have created a simple Google Cloud VM and enabled OS Login for it. Login using SSH keys works perfectly fine.

I would now like to allow individual users to sign in with a fixed password as well (instead of the public key).

Unfortunately, this results in an error:

```sh
$ sudo passwd myusername
passwd: Authentication token manipulation error
passwd: password unchanged
```

or

```sh
$ passwd
passwd: Authentication token manipulation error
passwd: password unchanged
```

Is it impossible to set passwords for users managed by OS Login?

Answer (score 1):

By default, password-based logins are disabled for Google Cloud VMs.

- Log in to the instance.
- Edit the file **/etc/ssh/sshd_config**.
- Look for the line **PasswordAuthentication no**.
- Change it to yes.
- Restart the SSH server: **sudo systemctl restart sshd**.

There are other password related settings. Review the [documentation](https://www.ssh.com/academy/ssh/sshd_config):

Comment: Thank you John! I changed this setting, but can still not set passwords with the same error as above. However, I noticed that this issue only applies to users provisioned by OS Login. I can manually create a user straight in the VM and assign that one a password just fine (and log in with it afterwards). This is a feasible workaround for me.

Comment: I left out a requirement. **VMs accept connections only from user accounts that have the necessary IAM roles in your project or organization** This link will help: https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/oslogin/set-up-oslogin#configure_users

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and found a very simple solution in [Goggle's Documentation.](https://cloud.google.com/architecture/chrome-desktop-remote-on-compute-engine#set_a_user_password)

> The user account created by Compute Engine doesn't have a password.
> However, several desktop environments require one for unlocking
> screensavers and authorizing administrative actions. It is therefore
> important to set a password for your user:
>
> 1. Connect to the instance using SSH, as you did when you first set up the instance.
> 2. Create a password for the user:
>
>    sudo passwd $(whoami)

Comment: This doesn't work when OS Login is enabled