# Cannot login to ssh through web browser in Google Cloud

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

One particular user logs in to the console(logs in fine) and he clicks on SSH from the web browser. However he is getting the below error

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xYHxr.png)

then he tried logging in from the cloud console using the below command

```
gcloud compute ssh instance-name --zone ZONE
```

then getting the below error.
[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yN2Vn.jpg)

He is able to login to the console using the organization credentials and the password is not expired.

Comment: The user is logging in with an invalid account OR someone has modified the system incorrectly to allow password logins. By default, Google Cloud Compute Engine VMs do not allow password logins. Find someone that knows Linux user administration to repair and correctly set up the login system.

Comment: @JohnHanley I think you've already answered that here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71593412/549372

Comment: Thanks @JohnHanley. When I logged in using my id it is not asking for the password and it generates the sshkey. I am able to login to the ssh from the browser. Also the passwordauthentication is gives as 'yes' in the sshd_config file

Comment: also I just now saw that there is a start up script as userdel -r "useridwhich is not able to access" defined in the host. How do i find who updated this for the VM?

Answer (score 1):

Google machines have password auth disabled by default.

I would suggest deploying a fresh machine.

Or ask the person who changed the auth configs about what they did.

Answer (score 1):

Here are the steps to check out when you were not able to SSH VM.

1. Firewall open port 22 and check network tag.
2. Check CPU utilization to avoid high CPU usage.
3. SSH key is correct?

---

You can check the error logs in the serial console.

Comment: I'd rather use the serial console to fix SSHd... it's always the last resort.

Comment: @MartinZeitler. When I logged in using my id it is not asking for the password and it generates the sshkey. I am able to login to the ssh from the browser. Also the passwordauthentication is gives as 'yes' in the sshd_config file

Answer (score 1):

Likely you'd have to disable OSLogin. Don't use password authentication; it's just insecure ...
GCE permits to provision RSA private keys with project/machine meta data. Only because someone didn't understand how it works, this doesn't justify tearing down the default security measures.

Comment: also I just now saw that there is a start up script as userdel -r "useridwhich is not able to access" defined in the host. How do i find who updated this for the VM?